How can I sync my laptop time with BD-Spot dog? it doesn't let me do SSH so I can't use NTP
when I am moving the Spot using Joystick and ROS it the time difference between robot and my laptop slowly increases and after 1 minutes it rejects all of my joystick commands with this error: The command was received after its max_duration had already passed.
I have tried using chrony, NTP and BD documentation about Spot but the none of them work.

"none of them work" -- please elaborate. It's hard to help without knowing what didn't work.
